# On the (not so) lenghty and demanding proof of Meyer that progressively measurable modifications exists

Tags: proof-verification, stochastic-processes, probability

In Paul Meyer's Book Probability and Potential one finds the following theorem

[image]

The proof begins in page 69 and ends in page 70.

Here is a Sketch of the proof:

0) Consider $X: \Bbb{R}_+ \times \Omega$ a measurable and adapted process

1) Consider $X^n(t, \omega) = \sum_{k \geq 0} 1_{A^n_k}(t) H^n_k(\omega)$ with $$ \Bbb{E}[X_t- X^n_t] \leq \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$

This is the hard step. But if we accept that then We are almost done

2 )

[image]

3 ) Note that $Y^n(t \omega) = \sum_{k \geq 0} 1_{A^n_k}(t) G^n_k(\omega) $ is progressively measurable

4 ) Conclude that $$\Bbb{E}[|X_t - Y^n_t| \wedge 1] \leq \frac{1}{2^n}.$$Since $\sum \frac{1}{2^n}$ is finite the convergence in probability follows by Markov inequality. Indeed $$P(|Y^m_t - Y^n_t|> \epsilon) \leq \sum_{k \geq n}\frac{1}{\epsilon} \Bbb{E}[|Y^{k+1}_t - Y^k_t| \wedge 1] \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 0. $$
Then comes the conclusion
[image]

---

Questions concerning this proof are:

1)How do we find the sequence $X^n$??

Before considering this sequence, the author says:

[image]

For completeness, the metric $\pi(f,g) = \Bbb{E}[|f-g|\wedge 1]$.

The discussion in II.10  boils to

[image]

2) Ok

3) Ok

4) How do conclude that $Y$ is a modification of $X$ given that $\pi$ is a pseudo metric?